# How to divide period to weeks start from Saturday and end with Friday?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a period suppose its Start from 01/12/2022  and end in 30/12/2022 I want to divide this period to weeks the week must start from Saturday and end in Friday so expected result should be :

[image]

How I can do this using  SQL server query

Comment: You question is way to vague to respond. what is a period?
What exactly do you expect to get?
How did this task end up with you if you have no previous experince with the basics required to full fill it?

Comment: SQL or C# is very vague; choose a language and go with that. If you haven't experimented yet, then I suggest you do first and then explain  where you're stuck in that experimentation/attempt.

Comment: I found the solution thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar solution to Enigmativity's, for those who are not yet familiar with queries.
In general, you can find out the first day of the week like this:
(and choose which day the week should start)

```
DateTime curDate = new DateTime(2022, 12, 1);
DateTime result = FirstDateOfWeek(curDate, DayOfWeek.Saturday);

DateTime FirstDateOfWeek(DateTime day, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek=DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
  int minus = day.DayOfWeek - firstDayOfWeek;
  if (minus == 0)
     return day.Date;
  if (minus < 0)
     minus = 7 + minus;
  return day.Date - TimeSpan.FromDays(minus);
}
```

Just add 7 to the result for the next week.

Comment: Rather than `day.Date - TimeSpan.FromDays(minus)` you could do `day.Date.AddDays(-minus)`. Seems more straight forward that way to me.

Comment: Interestingly, your code boils down to `day.Date.AddDays(-((7 + day.DayOfWeek - firstDayOfWeek) % 7))`.

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of trial and error you need this:

```
DateTime StartOfWeek(DateTime when) =>
    when.AddDays(-((8 + (int)when.DayOfWeek) % 7));
```

Here's a table of output:

```
var table = 
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, 31)
        .Select(x => new DateTime(2022, 12, 1).AddDays(x))
        .GroupBy(x =>  StartOfWeek(x))
        .Select(x => new
        {
            from = x.Min(),
            to = x.Max(),
            start = x.Key
        });
```

[image: output]